# RegQueryValueEx() always returns only 4 bytes of the string

Tags: c++, registry

What im doing wrong this time? The following code always returns 4 bytes only, instead of the whole string:

```
HKEY hkey;
DWORD dwType, dwSize;

char keybuffer[512];

if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("software\\company name\\game name"), 0, KEY_READ, &hkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    dwType = REG_SZ;
    dwSize = sizeof(keybuffer);
    RegQueryValueEx(hkey, TEXT("setting"), NULL, &dwType, (PBYTE)&keybuffer, &dwSize);
    RegCloseKey(hkey);
}
```

Even if i change dwSize to anything, it will still return 4 bytes.

**Edit:** Apparently there was no bug in above code, but somewhere else -_-

Comment: Are you sure `setting` key is `REG_SZ` and not `REG_DWORD`?

Comment: By the way, this code stores a registry value in keybuffer, not a registry key.

Comment: Voted to close as "no longer relevant" because the problem had nothing to do with the question being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two more potential pitfalls here. First, as Francis mentioned, you should check the return value. Do the 4 bytes actually correspond to the string characters you expect? They might be anything. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> If the buffer specified by lpData parameter is not large enough to hold the data, the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA and stores the required buffer size in the variable pointed to by lpcbData. In this case, the contents of the lpData buffer are undefined.

The second potential pitfall is that you're using a `char` array with a function that takes `TCHAR` parameters. If you're compiling for Unicode, the compiler will happily let you write a wide string to your narrow string buffer, due to the cast to `PBYTE`. It's safer to either use `TCHAR` consistently or don't use it at all (i.e. call `RegQueryValueExA` or `RegQueryValueExW`).

Comment: bug found, apparently it had nothing to do with these registry functions -_-

Answer (score 3):

I remember the registry key name from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141751/how-to-set-a-value-in-windows-registry-c).  You had a problem creating the value.  In that thread, the value was created as a DWORD, 4 bytes.  That's too much of a coincidence.  Run Regedit.exe and navigate to the key you created and check what the value type is.  If it is still a DWORD, you'll never get more than 4 bytes back, even if you ask for a string.

Fix the code that creates the value, make sure you create a REG_SZ, not a REG_DWORD.  Use Regedit.exe to delete the old value before you run the code.

Comment: i dont create this key, its createn by another program. when i open regedit, i see the complete string there, but when i try to get the value, i get only the first 4 bytes of it.

Comment: Hmm, heckofa coincidence.  No idea then, your code runs fine when I try it.  *Always* check the return value of API functions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an answer, but...

1. you don't need to assign dwType = REG_SZ, because dwType is a output param.
2. you can use NULL to replace (PBYTE)&keybuffer to see how much space does it want
3. are you sure HKEY_CURRENT_USER is correct, or LOCAL_MACHINE? And is "setting" in REG_SZ for both CURRENT_USER and LOCAL_MACHINE, if you have both of them?
4. check the return value of RegQueryValueEx.

Answer (score 1):

(PBYTE)&keybuffer - wrong. must be (PBYTE)keybuffer.

Comment: It doesn't matter, same thing.